# Why getting ThreadAbortException

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I have a .Net Compact Framework application which calls a ReadFile method of a driver, after application runs for some time , I get threadAbortException, I never call Thread.Abort(),
My question is what is causing ThreadAbortException ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You question is extremely vague.  Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try debugging. Figure out what part of your code causes the problem then provide more information and then someone can probably answer your question without having to make a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

As you are connected to the device via debugger you will also see debug messages issued by other processes and threads. The debug channel is a broadcast and so you will see also debug messages which are not issued by your app.

Possibly the driver or a referenced library fires the debug message.

For example if I am using a OEM library and start to use some object of that and then dispose it, I will see debug messages with 'ThreadAbort()' exception too. But this is normal as the library uses a internal thread and kills it using Thread.Abort() when I dispose the object.